# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: _flutter on flutter web

Tags: flutter, web

When I go to my website, “example.com” I receive this error:
[image: error]
We recenently had HTTPS setup so that may be the problem, but for now I’ve tried the following:

- Flutter clean and building the application again
- Made base href “./“ instead of “/"
- Tried adding main.dart.js file to index.html as script
- Accessing website from mobile and desktop
- Accessing website from HTTP, HTTPS, and WWW
- Accessing on a new device to see if it was a caching problem (it was not)

Here is my index.html file:

```
<script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        }
      }).then(function(engineInitializer) {
        return engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
      }).then(function(appRunner) {
        return appRunner.runApp();
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Here is my flutter doctor logs:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.1, on macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-arm64, locale
    en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] Connected device (5 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Thanks

EDIT: I uploaded the site to firebase and it worked fine so I have a feeling it has to do with HTTPS recently being setup.

Answer (score 0):

After messing with the flutter.js file with no fix, I reverted to running `flutter clean` and `flutter build web` 3 times and it is finally fixed and my site is now working as normal. Weird bug.

Answer (score -1):

Replacing this line

```html
<script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
```

With

```html
<script src="main.dart.js" defer></script>
```

Will resolve the issue as flutter build web doesn't produces flutter.js

Comment: flutter.js was in my build folder so this answer doesn’t work.

Comment: For me, it was flutter.js. If you can perhaps share details of your error, that would be helpful

Comment: The details of the error are in the question. If you look, I already tried your answer.